# Saving default data in app ios swift core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want my ios swift app to already have some data in its core data when a user downloads from app store. What are the ways in which i can achieve this ?

Comment: simply add a json file with data in your app...at first time installation of app import all the data from json to coredata. Now show 7 perform opertaion on coredata

Answer (score 1):

You can add the data you want to have previously and include the file in your bundle resources. Then at runtime what you need to do is copy that file to users document directory for live usage and insert update operations should be performed in the live usage file which is in document directory or anywhere you copied. This would be the best approach i think.

So in case of you its a CoreData file. What you have to do is do everything as systematic until you have the required data in the sqlite file of CoreData. Then copy that file and keep in bundle resource. At runtime when app starts before fetching anything and initializing the core data objets, replace the file in the destination directory with the bundle file.

Comment: Thanks alot "Mahesh" ... helped alot

Comment: welcome...happy coding!